# PTCHY LGT MOD SEV coverage on WX charts?

Tags: weather, aeronautical-charts, ppl

On GFAs, TAFs, METARs we see PTCHY LGT TURB, MOD TURB, -RA, +RA, etc. I was wondering where could I find the technical definition of these terms? For example the percentage coverage of these weather phenomena or the sky coverage in terms of oktas?

Comment: Check NOAA's [FMH-1](https://www.icams-portal.gov/resources/ofcm/fmh/FMH1/fmh1_2019.pdf) and see if that answers your question; if not I'll try to put together an answer later.

Comment: Please be sure to mark the below answer as „accepted“, if you feel it has answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

For the [METAR codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR) you mentioned (compare [United States of America Aeronautical Contractions, Section 1: Decode](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/cnt_html/chap2_section_1.html)):

| abbrev. | term |
| --- | --- |
| `PTCHY` | patchy |
| `MOD` | moderate |
| `TURB` | turbulence |
| `RA` | rain |
| `LGT` | light |

The conditions for Light Rain are defined in the [Federal Meteorological Handbook-1](https://www.icams-portal.gov/resources/ofcm/fmh/FMH1/fmh1_2019.pdf).

The conditions for Light/Moderate Turbulence is defined by the ICAO ([I could only find the SkyBrary definition, not the original source in the ICAO documents](https://skybrary.aero/articles/turbulence)).

The conditions for Patchy ("covers 25% or less") are defined by the FAA, [eg. in 7930.2 Notices to Air Missions (NOTAM)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/notam_html/chap5_section_1.html#dPJWX16eShaw).